# Nami Wallet access

Tags: wallet, nami

Cpu crashed,got new cpu, not able to send or receive in Nami wallet, no customer service email. How can I get customer service to Nami Wallet developers with no email available?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are referring to your computer with "cpu".

There is no customer support for Nami. You need your 24 words recovery phrase (that you wrote down when creating the wallet) to restore it. After doing this, you should see your funds and can use them as before.

You can find instructions on how to restore a wallet here: https://metaroids.com/learn/how-to-use-nami-wallet-full-guide/#How_to_Restore_Nami_Wallet